# Are the even function closed in $C [-1,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

We have a space $V=C ([-1,1]; \mathbb{R})$ with inner product:

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) dx.$$

Are the even function closed in $V$ in norm induced by inner product?

Comment: You perhaps meant $\int_{-1}^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a continuous map: $T:V\to V$ defined as $(Tf)(x)=f(x)-f(-x).$ (Left for you to prove: $T$ is continuous.)

Now the space of even functions is $T^{-1}(\{\mathbf 0\})$ where $\mathbf 0$ is the zero function, and $\{\mathbf 0\}$ is closed in $V.$ (Why?)

Comment: Thanks! Now, all is clear for me. It was realy helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We note that $$\int_{-1}^1 (f(x) - f_n(x))^2 dt = \int_{0}^1 (f(x) - f_n(x))^2 dt + \int_{0}^1 (f(-x) - f_n(x))^2 dt \rightarrow 0,$$ thus as each integral is positive $f$ is even as required.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of even functions in $C[-1,1]$ such that $f_n\xrightarrow{L^2} f$. We have:

$$\|x\mapsto f(x) - f(-x)\|_2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{\|x \mapsto f_n(x) - f_n(-x)\|_2}_{=0} = 0$$

so $f(x) = f(-x), \forall x \in [-1,1]$.

For an alternative proof, note that the space of even functions and the space of odd functions are orthogonal complements of each other (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1139086/144766) for example). Then in particular, both subspaces are closed.